# How to lower the bool value in webservice response and XML file

Tags: asp.net, .net, xml, web-services, boolean

In my application i have set of Web-Service which return Bool value in from of camel case i.e. **"True" instead of "true" and "False" instead of "false"** and same goes in XML file which is get from the system.

I need suggestion that how can I modify the output so that bool value can be lowered as true and false so that I doesn't have to apply major changes in my code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you really facing a problem if you use "True" instead of "true"?

Comment: @sachin because it take as a string instead of bool value

Comment: so you can use bool.TryParse to parse your string value to bool wherever you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure If you got you correctly but here is what I understand.
if you want to replace it for a string value you could just use

```
var result = yourString.ToLower();
```

and If this occurs multiple time in the xml file and you want to replace all occurrences
you could try replacing it

```
var result = yourString.Replace("True","true");
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You should return `Json` result in order to communicate with clients. In your case, the string of something like `JsonConverter.Serialize(new { result = true})` should be used.

Otherwise, the ASP.NET will use the `.ToString()` method of an object you specify as a action method result. Instance of `bool` returns its `"True"` or `"False"` in camel case.

Comment: i cannot convert whole system to return json as a response i want faster and less modifcation required method

Comment: @ArjunSharma should have thinked of that earlier. Try hooking into javascript ajax response handler to lowercase bool results.

Comment: a) `You should return Json result in order to communicate with clients`. No Json is not a must. b) It is `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` not `JsonConverter.Serialize`

Comment: @I4V a) I didn't tell it is a must. But a good practice. b) It says "something like". Do you read before downvoting?